# Bending stiffness and flexural rigidity of idealized slender structures under stretch

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

In the literature of applied maths/computational physics interested in slender structures, I find that there are two choices for the basic behaviour of the bending stiffness of slender structures when they are being stretched.

I denote curvilinear coordinate $S$ in reference configuration $R$, $s$ in current configuration $C$, and $\lambda = ds/dS$ is the stretch.

In [approach 1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2008.11.036), bending stiffness $\tilde{B}$ is considered constant, with bending energy $\int_C \tilde{B} \kappa^2 ds$ in the current configuration $C$. Then with constant $\tilde{B}$ the tension in material has a contribution from bending even if there is no stretch. Here $\kappa$ is current configuration's curvature.

In [approach 2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-87710-5) (which unfortunately do not give the energy corresponding to their mechanical balance), I understand that bending stiffness is a property of the reference configuration $R$, with bending energy $\int_R {B} c^2 dS$ in that configuration. Then there is no contribution of the bending in the longitudinal direction. Here $c$ is the derivative of the angle of stucture wrt to $S$, so actual curvature is $\lambda^{-1} c$.

If one takes into account the stretch, the models need $\tilde{B} = \lambda B$ to agree. But in each case, the authors take their choice of modulus to be a constant. I believe I can show that in approach 2, the flexural rigidity is the quantity which is conserved in the course of deformation, which would seem a better idealized material probably.

I'd welcome a reference or explanations comparing these two different approaches. Knowing whether they have a name would also be good, in the literature I've come across one has to guess/reverse engineer which one is being used.

Comment: The general moments/forces $(M,N) $  relate to  $(\epsilon, \kappa) $ are  given by AEH Love etal.

Comment: @Narasimham Are you thinking of the elastica chapter in Love's Math theory of elasticity? He uses approach 1 for the bending of a rod under load, but as far as I can see doesn't discuss whether flexural rigidity is constant in that case or the possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the answer, but I believe I have found the explanation of why  this choice is of negligible importance.

[Audoly and Pomeau (2010)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/elasticity-and-geometry-9780198506256?cc=fr&lang=en&) explain that *"elastic rod models combining extension of the centre line and bending (or twisting) *[which]* are very popular in the literature [...] are in fact of very limited use.*" They specify *"Indeed, for a slender rod, only two cases are possible generically, as we show below: when the loading is moderate, the centre line remains inextensible and the classical inextensible rod model applies; when the loading is stronger, the centre line stretches, and bending and twisting forces become negligible."*

That would explain why previous research has made either of the choices I give in my question and have not focused on making models agree, if anyway differences are always negligible.

It remains unclear to me that the proof in the above and in [Marigo & Meunier 2006](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10659-005-9036-y) which they cite is sufficient to say that there will be no difference in the case of localised bending.